Create dynamic linked service with self-hosted integration runtime as a dynamic parameter in adf
I have 5 self hosted  integration runtimes like shir, shir 1,shir2,...shir5.
I want to create a linked service to a SQL MI in adf but want to dynamically pass the integration runtime values.
whats the way to do it? i tried couple ways but no clue.
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "AccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "IntegrationRuntimeName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "LS_Dynamic_LinkedService_ADLS",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
        "typeProperties": {
          "url": "[concat('https://', parameters('AccountName'), '.dfs.core.windows.net')]"
        },
        "connectVia": {
          "referenceName": "[parameters('IntegrationRuntimeName')]",
          "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        },
        "authenticationType": "ManagedIdentity",
        "managedIdentity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

i tried this one too..
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "LS_Dynamic_LinkedService_ADLS_hello",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
        "typeProperties": {
          "url": "[concat('https://', '@{linkedService().AccountName}', '.dfs.core.windows.net')]"
        },
        "connectVia": {
          "referenceName": "[concat('@{linkedService().IntegrationRuntimeName}')]",
          "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        },
        "authenticationType": "ManagedIdentity",
        "managedIdentity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned",
          "managedIdentityObjectId": "a1037f20-9968-4600-8b67-5955521f27b5"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "AccountName": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "IntegrationRuntimeName": {
          "type": "String"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}



Unfortunately,based on my understanding ADF doesnt support parameterization of the integration runtimes within linked services unlike other parameters within the database linked service.
